# Function returns pointer to nothing?

Tags: c++

I have function that should convert char* to wchar_*. But it doesn't - I have just strange string of 3 spaces. Is that because  GetWC returns pointer to not existing string?

```
const wchar_t *GetWC(const char *c)
{
    size_t cSize = strlen(c)+1;
    std::wstring wc( cSize, L'#');
    mbstowcs( &wc[0], c, cSize );
    return wc.c_str();
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *g ="aaa";

    const wchar_t* f= GetWC(g);
    wcout<<f;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Return `std::wstring` by value, to preserve its value. Anyone who really needs a pointer can call `c_str()` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`wc.c_str()` is not valid after `GetWC` returns.  `wc` is a local variable